# Numpy matrix is reseting the values inside it

Tags: numpy, python-imaging-library

I am implementing a co-occurrence matrix for an image to be able to detect the edges of an image through the change in brightness. So I made a 256x256 numpy matrix to store the co-occurrences, and then I wrote a function that turns all of the values of occurrences in the matrix to 0 if the change between them is less than a certain value like 30, ie the difference between the i and j of the matrix is less than 30 then the value inside that cell is turned into 0.

Here is the function, it takes the co-occurrence matrix and turn the values into 0.

```
def nullify(matrix):
   for i in range (0,matrix.shape[0]):
      for j in range(0,matrix.shape[1]):
          if(abs(i-j)<30):
             matrix[i,j]=0
    return matrix
```

But for some reason it turn the entire matrix into 0's, the function work perfectly when I'm using a smaller matrix like a 3x3.

This is the function that I use to calculate the Cooccurrence

```
def calculateCooccurrence(im):
    Horizontal = np.zeros((256, 256))
    
    for i in range (0,im.size[0]):
        for j in range (0,im.size[1]-1):
            pixelRGB = im.getpixel((i,j))
            R,G,B = pixelRGB 
            brightness = int(sum([R,G,B])/3)
            pixelRGB1 = im.getpixel((i,j+1))
            R1,G1,B1 = pixelRGB 
            brightness1 = int(sum([R1,G1,B1])/3)
            Horizontal[brightness,brightness1]+=1
            
    Vertical = np.zeros((256, 256))
    for i in range (0,im.size[0]-1):
        for j in range (0,im.size[1]):
            pixelRGB = im.getpixel((i,j))
            R,G,B = pixelRGB 
            brightness = int(sum([R,G,B])/3)
            pixelRGB1 = im.getpixel((i+1,j))
            R1,G1,B1 = pixelRGB 
            brightness1 = int(sum([R1,G1,B1])/3)
            Vertical[brightness,brightness1]+=1
            
    return Horizontal,Vertical
```

And this is what I do exactly

```
horiz,vertic=calculateCooccurrence(im2)
horizon=nullify(horiz)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are some things to point about your code. I can't tell why your entire matrix turns into zeros, but these are things that should help you:

1. This might be due to formatting in stackoverflow, but your matrix is returned after the first iteration of the i-loop.
2. You actually are not working on the values of the matrix. You iterate over the range 0...256. This will set all values close to the diagonal to 0. Based on your text where you say that you want to detect the edges, I am not sure if this is what you actually want to do.
3. instead of creating a variable named difference you can also put it simply in the if-statement `if(abs(i-j)<30:`

Edit: Found the problem: Your code works intended, which is the problem. All the elements are on the diagonal. I just used a test image myself and found that `np.sum(matrix)` and `np.trace(matrix)` returned the same result. So when your code eliminates all elements along the diagonal, it turns all elements to 0.

Comment: 1)Yes its a formatting issue the matrix is returned after both loops, 2) This is what I'm trying to do with the function exactly I use this matrix output to remove all the pixels that were turned to 0 here leaving me with the pixels that have a change in brightness more than 30 which are the edges of the objects in image, 3) thank you I fixed this

Comment: What I don't understand is why my entire 256x256 matrix is turned into 0's, the same doesn't happen when i change the function to fit a 3x3 matrix that I was using to test the function and using the difference of 1 only the function works properly

Comment: I've tried setting the values inside the matrix into 1's instead of 0's to test, it would return the matrix with the ones in the proper place but the values that where inside the matrix that where not turned into 1 would be 0's, I do not understand how as in no part in my code do I turn them to 0's

Comment: Did you check if the matrices you use as input have the correct values? I tested your first function (like the other answer) and it works fine for me. Maybe the problem is within the matrix you give to the function.

Comment: Yes I printed it right before it enters the for loop the values are all there

Comment: Found the problem: Your code works intended, which is the problem. All the elements are on the diagonal. I just used a test image myself and found that `np.sum(matrix)` and `np.trace(matrix)` returned the same result. So when your code eliminates all elements along the diagonal, it turns all elements to 0.

Comment: You're right, thank you, I imagined there must be some change in the brightness between pixel, this is weird but Thanks again for your test I'm not sure how much longer this would have taken me to find.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to work properly for Python 3.7.7 and NumPy 1.18.1:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> matrix = np.ones((256, 256))
>>> def nullify(matrix):
...    for i in range (0,matrix.shape[0]):
...       for j in range(0,matrix.shape[1]):
...           if(abs(i-j)<30):
...              matrix[i,j]=0
...    return matrix
... 
>>> nullify(matrix)
array([[0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., ..., 1., 1., 1.],
       ...,
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 1., ..., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

You can see that the elements far away from the diagonal remain unchanged. You should provide a minimal working example of what goes wrong in your code.

Comment: I added the other functions to provide more context to the issue, I tried printing the matrix before it enters the for loop and there were values inside for some reason when it enters the loops it is turned into an empty matrix. To test this further I changed the code so it turns the values into 1's and it did turn them into 1's but the values that where inside the matrix were turned into 0's.